# Keras - Input a 3 channel image into LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have read a sequence of images into a numpy array with shape `(7338, 225, 1024, 3)` where `7338` is the sample size, `225` are the time steps and `1024 (32x32)` are flattened image pixels, in `3` channels (RGB).

I have a sequential model with an LSTM layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(225, 1024, 3))
```

But this results in the error:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

The [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) mentions that the input tensor for LSTM layer should be a `3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`, but in my case my `input_dim` is 2D.

What is the suggested way to input a 3 channel image into an LSTM layer  in Keras?

Comment: have you tried giving input_shape=X_train.shape[1:] . Assuming that X_train is your input array

Comment: Yes, I have. 
`X_train.shape[1:]` gives me `(225, 1024, 3)` which is what was hard-coded as the `input_shape` param

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the number of images to be a sequence (like a movie with frames), you need to put pixels AND channels as features:

```
input_shape = (225,3072)  #a 3D input where the batch size 7338 wasn't informed
```

If you want more processing before throwing 3072 features into an LSTM, you can combine or interleave 2D convolutions and LSTMs for a more refined model (not necessarily better, though, each application has its particular behavior).

You can also try to use the new [ConvLSTM2D](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d), which will take the five dimensional input:

```
input_shape=(225,32,32,3) #a 5D input where the batch size 7338 wasn't informed
```

---

I'd probably create a convolutional net with several `TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))` and `TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(...))` before adding a `TimeDistributed(Flatten())` and finally the `LSTM()`. This will very probably improve both your image understanding and the performance of the LSTM.

Comment: I thought of reshaping my data from `(1024, 3)` to `3072`, but I already had the data in batch size of `7338`, and reshaping was taking a lot of time.
And the LSTM is part of an auto encoder, so wasn't sure if this reshaping would help my cause.
Will try reshaping first, then with `ConvLSTM2D` and `TimeDistributed` layers. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Reshaping taking time??? That doesn't sound ok.... the LSTM would be very very slow, though....

Comment: Yes, I think that's cause I'll be reshaping `1651050 (7738*225)` instances. So, instead of doing it all together, I resorted to Keras model method of [fit_generator()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator), where I create a generator method to reshape the data set, while training.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a guide how to create RNNs with nested structures in the keras guide which enable arbitrary input types for each timestep: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#rnns_with_listdict_inputs_or_nested_inputs