# Keras - Embedding to LSTM: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to input an array with 1 sample, three time-steps, and three features as a test to make sure my model will work when I start working with actual data.

Here's my input data that I'm pretty sure is formatted correctly so that the above description is correct:

```
x_train = array([[[811, 435, 54], [0, 850, 435], [435, 582, 558]]])
y_train = array([[[0], [0], [276]]])
```

And here's my model that should embed each word (what the numbers point to), then feed it into the LSTM layer and then the TimeDistributed layer should enable me to predict three words in the output:

```
vector_dim = 64
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=len(vocab), output_dim=vector_dim, mask_zero=False, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))  # therefore input shape is (3, 3)
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
# model.add(CuDNNGRU(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(vocab), activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc'])
```

However I get the error: `Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 3, 3, 64]`

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my model configuration, or data shape? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just found another question with an answer that seems to be working, however it's slightly different than my use case. Going to post my own solution here once I get it working

Comment: Can't you represent your data as 3 data points? Instead of making this one? Because you have 3 labels? You seem to have time series within time series which is not possible to work with simple LSTM

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but my input is shaped for LSTM (batch_size, time_steps, seq_len: None, 3, 3) and if there was no TimeDistributed there, the output would be 1 number instead of 3. However when I add embedding, it adds another dimension so that it's incompatible with LSTM. I just figured out I need three input layers, one for each time-step and I embed the list of numbers and concatenate it down to my LSTM layer below, that seems to be doing the trick fine now

Comment: What I'm saying is, you have a `(1, 3, 3)` data for `x`. Normally, timeseries data has the shape (batch size, time steps, input size). You have an input_size of 1. So in reality you have a `(1,3,3,1)` sized `x`. Which is not the typical data expected by an LSTM layer.

Comment: If there's an embedding layer like mine has, yeah it will make it a 4D array which isn't compatible with LSTM (1, 3, 3, vector_length), I realize that. But the data above definitely will work for pure LSTM, if you're saying that. The issue was going from 1 time-step to more than one, in that case embedding would return a 4D array when I needed 3D for the LSTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/how-to-use-embedding-with-3d-tensor-in-keras), I was able to figure out I needed three inputs, one for each time-step (each time-step is a list of number indexes representing a words, or a sentence). Then I apply embedding on each input and concatenate to one LSTM layer!

```
vector_dim = 32
input_a = Input(shape=x_train1.shape[1:])
output_a = Embedding(input_dim=len(vocab), output_dim=vector_dim, mask_zero=False, input_shape=(x_train1.shape[1:]))(input_a)

input_b = Input(shape=x_train2.shape[1:])
output_b = Embedding(input_dim=len(vocab), output_dim=vector_dim, mask_zero=False, input_shape=(x_train2.shape[1:]))(input_b)

input_c = Input(shape=x_train2.shape[1:])
output_c = Embedding(input_dim=len(vocab), output_dim=vector_dim, mask_zero=False, input_shape=(x_train2.shape[1:]))(input_c)

concat = keras.layers.concatenate([output_a, output_b, output_c], axis=-1)
# concat2 = keras.layers.concatenate([concat, output_c])
lstm_unified = GRU(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(concat)
# lstm_unified2 = GRU(24, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(lstm_unified)
final_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(vocab), activation='softmax'))(lstm_unified)

model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b, input_c], outputs=final_output)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc'])
```

My input data now looks like this (for 1 sample with 24 features and 3 time-steps. each array is a time-step):

```
x_train1 = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3428, 8443, 12703, 8443, 4382, 8443, 3589, 8443, 11952, 8443, 6621, 8443, 13192]])
x_train2 = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3428, 8443, 5709, 8443, 6621, 8443, 10901, 10000]])
x_train3 = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10396, 10000]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem has also troubled me a lot.
I learned from here.[Keras - Input a 3 channel image into LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671732/keras-input-a-3-channel-image-into-lstm) 
This is my code

```
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
filters=20,
kernel_size=(3, 3),
batch_input_shape=(None, 1, 32, 32, 3),
input_shape=(1, 32, 32, 3),
padding="same",
return_sequences=True,
data_format="channels_last"
))
```

Luckily, I found another convenient method: convert the rgb image to gray image.
And this can really solve this problem quickly!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with text, not images so I don't know if this would work out for me

Comment: Actually, stored in matrix, image almost hava no diference from text. All you need to do is that reshape the numpy array to 2D array. It seems that LSTM can only process 2D array, like this (None, 3, 512), which None is a placeholder for the batch size.

Comment: ConvLSTM2D may be useful. You can just reshape your input [3, 3, 63] into [1, 3, 3, 63] , so you can use ConvLSTM2D easily.