# keep getting ERROR : Input 0 of layer lstm_8 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 94, 94, 32)

Tags: python, arrays, deep-learning

I'm trying to do alphabet classification using LSTM model. Input is binary image of 96x96 size

first step is loading the data

```
DATADIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Mihir_etal_Assamese_Dataset/DATASET_1'

CATEGORIES = ['1','2','3','4','5']

kernel=np.ones((2,2), np.int8)
training_data = []

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    label = CATEGORIES.index(category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        
        ret,img_array = cv2.threshold(img_array,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
                
        gray = 255*(img_array < 128).astype(np.uint8) 
        coords = cv2.findNonZero(gray) # Find all zero points (text)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
        img_array = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] # Crop the image 
        img_array = 255*(img_array < 128).astype(np.uint8)
        img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (96,96),)
        
        training_data.append([img_array, label])
```

Then convert my list of training data into X, y array for model input

```
X = []
y = []

for data, label in training_data:
   X.append(data)
   y.append(label)

X= np.array(X).reshape(-1,96,96,1)  
y= np.array(y)
```

Then splitting dataset

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

building my model

```
from keras import Sequential

LSTM = tf.keras.layers.LSTM
Dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout
Dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense
Conv2D = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape = X_train.shape[:1]))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

I've tried all kinds of solutions but I keep getting a mismatch of dimensions in my model input. Tried removing adding Conv2D layer but it makes no difference. Still same error

Comment: The title looks an error message, the body just presents labelled code snippets: [What is your answerable programming question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ive added more details. i think something is wrong in the way im converting my training data into X,y to give the input for the model. Or is something wrong with the way ive built my model?

Comment: (As it is so easy to mistake "backticks" for apostrophes, just use `~~~`.)

Comment: ([look what the search engine apported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673249))

Comment: Alright I found the problem. While using multiple LSTM layers, you have to add return_sequence= True for all layers except the last one so every layer gets the proper input

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the problem. While using multiple LSTM layers, you have to add return_sequence= True for all layers except the last one so every layer gets the proper input.